# Bundle is failing to be able to find command with Capistrano for one app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, chef-infra

So, I have two apps.  One is a test app, and the other is my main app.  For my main app, I was having problems with getting pg to run.  I deleted and reran bundle install to try and fix that.  Now I get a problem where it says

> Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin' is not available,
>   DEBUG [d8683644]             usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
>   DEBUG [d8683644]             it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
>   DEBUG [d8683644]             to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353@global'.

Then it says

> c] Finished in 0.148 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
>    INFO [f5470eb6] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile on ec2***
>   DEBUG [f5470eb6] Command: cd /var/www/****/releases/20131221073614 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
>   DEBUG [f5470eb6]    bash: bundle: command not found

The weird thing is I can upload the main app with capistrano, no problem.  But when I have this run, I get a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this.  I upgraded capistrano/rvm to 0.1.0 and it works now.